# Installing and running Pl/SQL packages

Tags: oracle, plsql, package

I have the package.pkg and package.pkg files, how can i install and run it without using Pl/SQL Developer? is there anyway or i have to install Pl/SQL Developer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or in sql*plus (which is installed together with Oracle) you type @/path/to/package.pkg.
Make sure to end with a / (forward slash).

It should look something like this:

```
SQL> @proc.prc
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC(VAL1 IN NUMBER, VAL2 OUT NUMBER)
  2  AS
  3  BEGIN
  4     VAL2 := VAL1*2;
  5  END PROC;
  6  /

Procedure created.
```

Comment: and how would i call this PROC? i.e. from sqlplus ?? filename.methodname?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Developer is free and is produced by Oracle

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/index.html

as mentioned elsewhere, SQLPlus is available if you have the oracle client installed.

you can also look into http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ISQLPlus
if it installed on by the dbas

Comment: What if i don't want to use it? is there other way ?

Comment: @alee, you can use SQL Plus (above) which is installed with the oracle client software (I believe that sqlplusw.exe is no longer available but sqlplus.exe is runnable from the command prompt).  you can also you iSQL*Plus if your database is set up with it (http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ISQLPlus )

Answer (score 0):

Package scripts are just text, so any SQL interface will work.  The obvious choice is SQL*Plus, the text-based interface that is part of the full Oracle client installation.